# Rails + MySQL GROUP BY and find the MAX from GROUP

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, group-by

I have these two models `users` & `jobs` where the relationships are designed in this way.

**users**

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
+----+
```

**jobs**

```
+-----+---------+------------------+---------------------+
| id  | user_id | receiver_user_id | updated_at          |
+-----+---------+------------------+---------------------+
| 111 |       1 |                2 | 2015-06-18 08:23:55 |
| 112 |       1 |                2 | 2015-06-18 08:28:40 |
| 113 |       1 |                3 | 2015-06-18 08:37:32 |
| 114 |       1 |                3 | 2015-06-18 08:37:51 |
| 115 |       2 |                1 | 2015-06-18 09:28:49 |
| 116 |       1 |                4 | 2015-06-18 09:29:58 |
| 117 |       1 |                4 | 2015-06-18 10:20:29 |
+-----+---------+------------------+---------------------+
```

#### user.rb

```
has_many :sent_jobs, :class_name => "Job", :foreign_key => :user_id

has_many :received_jobs, :class_name => "Job", :foreign_key => :receiver_user_id

def jobs_sent_and_received
  Job.where("user_id = ? OR receiver_user_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
end
```

(This is the best way I could think of. Better if there is a way to combine `jobs_sent_and_received` to a single `has_many` relationship)

However my question is when `User => 1` search for jobs (sent/received) I need to get the very last Job from each other user.

So far this is what I tried:

```
job_ids = current_user.jobs_sent_and_received.select([:id, "MAX(updated_at)"]).group([:user_id, :receiver_user_id]).collect(&:id)

@jobs = Job.order("updated_at DESC").where(:id => job_ids)
```

With this approach I still get 2 records from `user id => 2` as `job.id 111, 115` But I only need `job.id => 115` in the result set.

Hope my question is clear. Appreciate any help on this. Thanks

#### Results (Current)

```
SELECT id, MAX(updated_at) FROM `jobs` WHERE (user_id = 1 OR receiver_user_id = 1) GROUP BY user_id, receiver_user_id;
+-----+---------------------+
| id  | MAX(updated_at)     |
+-----+---------------------+
| 111 | 2015-06-18 08:28:40 |
| 113 | 2015-06-18 08:37:51 |
| 116 | 2015-06-18 10:20:29 |
| 115 | 2015-06-18 09:28:49 |
+-----+---------------------+

   SELECT `jobs`.* FROM `jobs` WHERE `jobs`.`id` IN (111, 113, 116, 115) ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0

+-----+---------+------------------+
| id  | user_id | receiver_user_id |
+-----+---------+------------------+
| 115 |       2 |                1 |
| 113 |       1 |                3 |
| 111 |       1 |                2 |
| 116 |       1 |                4 |
+-----+---------+------------------+
```

#### Results (Expected)

```
+-----+---------------------+
| id  | MAX(updated_at)     |
+-----+---------------------+
| 114 | 2015-06-18 08:37:51 |
| 115 | 2015-06-18 09:28:49 |
| 117 | 2015-06-18 10:20:29 |
+-----+---------------------+

+-----+---------+------------------+
| id  | user_id | receiver_user_id |
+-----+---------+------------------+
| 114 |       1 |                3 |
| 115 |       2 |                1 |
| 117 |       1 |                4 |
+-----+---------+------------------+
```

Comment: if you want just job 115, you should not consider column receiver_user_id when grouping and searching. Can you describe what you want?

Comment: @rxing As per the data shown in the example yes I agree. But `user.id => 1`  has both `sent_jobs` as well as `received_jobs` - so `receiver_user_id ` is required.

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated the Expected result now

Comment: why is 111 not what you want?

Comment: @Strawberry The expected result should be 115, 113 and 117 - I've updated the question. Sorry

Comment: @Strawberry Yes you're right - I made a mistake when copying the results here - between user 1 and 2 there are 3 jobs exchanged. 111,112, 115 From this set the top most record based on the `updated_at` is  `115`. Between user 1 and 3 jobs 113, 114 - I need `114` from this group. Between user 1 and 4 jobs 116, 117 - from this group `117` should be selected. I have updated the question now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hadn't made so many errors in your result set, you could have had an answer yesterday ;-)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jobs;

CREATE TABLE jobs
(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,user_id INT NOT NULL
,receiver_user_id INT NOT NULL
,updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO jobs VALUES
(111,1,2,'2015-06-18 08:23:55'),
(112,1,2,'2015-06-18 08:28:40'),
(113,1,3,'2015-06-18 08:37:32'),
(114,1,3,'2015-06-18 08:37:51'),
(115,2,1,'2015-06-18 09:28:49'),
(116,1,4,'2015-06-18 09:29:58'),
(117,1,4,'2015-06-18 10:20:29');

SELECT a.*
  FROM jobs a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(id) max_id 
         FROM
            (
              SELECT id, user_id FROM jobs WHERE receiver_user_id = 1
              UNION
              SELECT id, receiver_user_id FROM jobs WHERE user_id = 1
            ) n
        GROUP 
           BY user_id
     ) b
   ON b.max_id = a.id;

+-----+---------+------------------+---------------------+
| id  | user_id | receiver_user_id | updated_at          |
+-----+---------+------------------+---------------------+
| 114 |       1 |                3 | 2015-06-18 08:37:51 |
| 115 |       2 |                1 | 2015-06-18 09:28:49 |
| 117 |       1 |                4 | 2015-06-18 10:20:29 |
+-----+---------+------------------+---------------------+
```